# Let $X=C[0,1]$ , $A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$, $f \in X$ show that $ \int_{0}^{x} fg$ is compact for any $g \in X$

Tags: functional-analysis

i)Let $X=C[0,1]$ , $A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$, $f \in X$ show that $ A(f)=\int_{0}^{x} fg$ is compact for any $g \in X$ fixed

ii) show that $ 0 \in \sigma(A)$ and see if it belongs to $\sigma_r(A)$ , $\sigma_c (A)$ or $\sigma_p(A)$

iii) Show that $ A^* \in \mathcal{L}$ is given by  $ A^* : \mu \rightarrow g(x)\mu(1-x) dx$ wher $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure

I have tryed to find a subsequence that is convergent in the image but don't really know how to approach it.

Comment: I guess $A(f)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)g(t)dt$ and $g$ is a fixed function in $C[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have already modified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $A$ is compact, we take a bounded sequence $(f_n)\subset X$, say $\|f_n\|\leq M$. If we show that $(A(f_n))$ is equicontinuous and bounded, then we are done, by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Indeed, we have that
$$|A(f_n)(x)|=|\int_0^xf_n(t)g(t)dt|\leq M\|g\|<\infty$$
so $(A(f_n))$ is uniformly bounded. Now let $\varepsilon>0$. We must find $\delta>0$ such that for all $f_n$ and for all $x_1,x_2$ it is $|x_1-x_2|<\delta\implies |A(f_n)x_1-A(f_n)x_2|<\varepsilon$
We have that $|A(f_n)x_1-A(f_n)x_2|=|\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f_n(t)g(t)dt|\leq M\|g\||x_1-x_2|$, so if $\varepsilon>0$ take as $\delta$ the quantity $\delta=\varepsilon/(M\|g\|)$ and you have equicontinuity.

By Arzela-Ascoli, $A$ is a compact operator.

Now to show that $0\in\sigma(A)$: it is by definition $0\not\in\sigma(A)$ if and only if $A$ is invertible. It is a very easy exercise to show that an operator $T:X\to X$ is compact and invertible if and only if $X$ is of finite dimension. Since the space $C[0,1]$ is **not** finite dimensional, it is immediate that $0\in\sigma(A)$.

Finally, the adjoint operator $A^*:C([0,1])^*\to C([0,1])^*$ is given by $A^*(\varphi):C([0,1])\to\mathbb{C}$ with $A^*(\varphi)(f)=\varphi(A(f))$. Now we know by the Riesz representation theorem that $C([0,1])^*$ is identified with the space of Radon measures $M[0,1]$ of bounded variation and the identification is via
$$\mu\leftrightarrow \psi_\mu(f):=\int f d\mu $$
Now  we have that for all $f\in C[0,1]$ it is $$A^*(\psi_\mu)(f)=\psi_\mu(A(f))=\int_0^1A(f)(x)d\mu(x)=\int_0^1\int_0^xf(t)g(t)dtd\mu(x)$$
By Fubini's theorem we may change the order of integration and obtain
$$A^*(\psi_\mu)(f)=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\int_t^1d\mu(x)dt=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\mu(1-t)dt=\psi_{g(t)\mu(1-t)}(f)\leftrightarrow g(t)\mu(1-t).$$

EDIT

Suppose $h\in C[0,1]$ with $\int_0^xh(t)dt=0$ for all $x$. Suppose that $h(x_0)\neq0$ for some $x_0\in[0,1]$. Wlog, suppose that $h(x_0)>0$. We may find a neighborhood $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ such that $h(x)>0$ there. Now $h$ is continuous and strictly positive on the compact set $[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$. Thus it attains a minimum value $h(\xi)>0$, so $\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}h(t)dt\geq2\delta h(\xi)>0$. But $\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}h(t)dt=\int_0^{x_0+\delta}h(t)dt-\int_0^{x_0-\delta}h(t)dt=0$, a contradiction. So $h=0$ everywhere.

Now this shows that if $A(f)=0$ if and only if $fg=0$ everywhere. This shows that $f$ must be zero when $g\neq0$. So, if $g(x)\neq0$ for all $x$ we have that $A$ is one to one. For the rest, use this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736394/point-spectrum-of-a-particular-operator/3736415#3736415).

Comment: in ii) how could I see if $ 0 \in \sigma_r(A), \sigma_c(A) $ or $ \sigma_p(A)$  depending on g ? I would have to see if the operator is injective and if $ran(A)$ is a proper dense subset or not amd if its closure is properly contained in $X$ , any idea?

Comment: @VeganMaths The operator is not onto: $A(f)$ is always differentiable, so the range of $A$ is a proper subspace. It is true however that differentiable functions are dense in $C[0,1]$, so the operator has dense range. An operator is invertible if and only if it has dense range and is bounded below. Since our operator has dense range but is not invertible, the operator is not bounded below.

Comment: Also the injectivity depends on $g$ if $g$=0 then of course it is not injective and then $0 \in \sigma_r(A) $, but I am not sure on how to determine in other cases if it is injective or not . I don't get why we need to know that it is not bounded below. And the other cases well, we already know that $ran(A)$ is a proper subset so if $A$ is injective , $0\in \sigma_c(A)$ but yet I don't know if its closure is a proper subset to determine wether $0 \in \sigma_r(A)$

Comment: Yes, so you are taking $ g= 1$ and $f=h$ right?

Comment: @VeganMaths No. I am proving something independent. I do that to conclude that $A$ is one to one if and only if the operator $f\mapsto fg$ is one to one, so their point spectrum is the same. But the other post computes the point spectrum of the 2nd operator. In other words $0\in\sigma_p(A)$ if and only if $g$ is $0$ on some subinterval of $[0,1]$. This answers the question, right?

Comment: @VeganMaths Please let me know if this covers your question.

Comment: I think so. Haven't been able to check rigorously the other post though. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: bound $\int_{x}^{x+h} f(t) g(t)\; dt$ and use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

Comment: It is already bounded as it is an integral of continuous functions in a bounded domain. To apply Arzela-Ascoli, I need to find a bounded , equicontinuous sequence in the image . I am a bit lost here.

Comment: To apply Arzela-Ascoli you show that the image of the unit ball is equicontinuous.  That involves the bound I mentioned.  You need to see how it depends on $h$.